# recursive functions within the class

Tags: dart

The below code worked fine with me while it is a stand a lone function

```
chunkBySize(List list, int size) => list.isEmpty
    ? list
    : ([list.take(size)]..addAll(chunkBySize(list.skip(size), size)));
```

And I was able to call it smoothly as:

```
void main() {
  var list = new List();
  list.addAll([1,2,3]);
  print(chunkBySize(list, 2));
}
```

but While trying to use it in a structure it failed with me, so I forced to write in the below way:

```
import 'dart:collection';

class functionalList<E> extends ListBase<E> {
  final List<E> l = [];  // or List l = new List();
  functionalList();
  .
  .
  .
  chunkBySize(int size) => _chunkBySize(l, size);

  _chunkBySize(List list, int size) => list.isEmpty
      ? list
      : ([list.take(size)]..addAll(_chunkBySize(list.skip(size), size)));
}
```

and was able to call it by:

```
void main() {
  var list = new functionalList();
  list.addAll([1,2,3]);
  print(list.chunkBySize(2));
}
```

Is there a way to simplify it within the class boy, i.e. replacing the below by single statement:

```
  chunkBySize(int size) => _chunkBySize(l, size);

  _chunkBySize(List list, int size) => list.isEmpty
      ? list
      : ([list.take(size)]..addAll(_chunkBySize(list.skip(size), size)));
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what "While trying to use it in a structure it failed with me" means?

Comment: What does "within the class boy" mean?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I added couple of line, hope the question is now clear!

Comment: please add an examples which gives you a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a local helper function inside the `chunkBySize` method.

```dart
class FunctionalList<E> extends ListBase<E> {
  ...
  List<Iterable<E>> chunkBySize(int size) {
    List<Iterable<E>> helper(Iterable<E> list, int size) => list.isEmpty 
        ? const [] 
        : ([list.take(size)]..addAll(_chunkBySize(list.skip(size), size);
    return helper(this, size);
  }
}
```

I don't find this particularly more readable than having an external helper function, but in this case it actually gives you *better* typing.

I'd probably write the function as:

```dart
List<Iterable<E>> chunkBySize(int size) {
  List<Iterable<E>> result = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < this.length; i += size) {
    result.add(this.getRange(i, min(i + size, this.length)));
  }
  return result;
}
```

Is both easier to read and more efficient.

The recursive function that repeatedly callas `addAll` will have time complexity that is quadratic in the length of the original list because it keeps copying the elements from one list to a another.